# Authorize user once and then make payments using an API

Tags: paypal, braintree

I'm looking for a paypal feature where a user grants permission to my webservice upon registration and then my webservice can take payments using an API when a user clicks a button on the website. I don't like it when a user has to go to the paypal gateway for each payment, it would be much better if it would be possible to initiate the payment when a user just clicks a button on the website.

I think braintree already offers this functionality with their paypal vault feature but is this available with paypal directly? I've taken a look at `Authentication` but it seems a bit drastic for normal users to authenticate full permissions to an app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for direct card payments(without navigating to Paypal checkout page) you will need to use [Dodirectpayment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoDirectPayment_API_Operation_NVP/) API calls which needs a PaYPal PRO account that is supported in US,UK and AU or you can try Braintree Dropin UI as well.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPDirectPayment/

Comment: Does this only work with cards? Not "regular" paypal payments from their balance or debit payments?